# Pinnect's htaccess rules to nginx

Tags: nginx

so I've been playing around with the rules trying to transform them, the pinnect script's rules are:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteBase /

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# fix for uploadify 302, 406 errors
SetEnvIfNoCase Content-Type "^multipart/form-data;" "MODSEC_NOPOSTBUFFERING=Do not buffer file uploads"
```

I have pinnect on pinnect/ on the server, however VB is running on the index for now,

I've tried

```
location /pinnect {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

And different variations of that, however let's say I go to the /install directory - it tries to redirect me to pinnect/forums.php(because of VB), if I try to go to index.php directly, an endless loop occurs, anyone could give me a hand with this?

EDIT:

So i've got this rule currently

```
location ~ ^/pinnect/index.php { try_files maintenance.html @index.php; }

location ~ ^/pinnect/ {
        rewrite ^/pinnect$                                             /pinnect/index.php       last;
        rewrite ^/pinnect/$                                             /pinnect/index.php       last;
        #rewrite ^/pinnect/([^.]+)$                                      /pinnect/index.php/$1 last;
        rewrite ^/pinnect/(.*)                                      /pinnect/index.php/$1 last;

}
```

However where ever I go, I get a 301, 302 so it's not behaving same way as the htaccess, could anyone help?

Comment: Hi! What HTTP status are you expecting?

Comment: As I got a -1, I think I didn't understand the question :D Are the redirections well working even if you are looking for rewrite and no redirect? Any precision?

Comment: Can you show your full config? It will be difficult to help until it's not clear how do you handle php and what locations already exist.

Answer (score -1):

If it's just a matter of status code returned, you might have to use `return` instruction on your `location` block.

```
location ~ ^/pinnect/index.php { try_files maintenance.html @index.php; }

location ~ ^/pinnect/ {
        rewrite ^/pinnect$                                             /pinnect/index.php       last;
        rewrite ^/pinnect/$                                             /pinnect/index.php       last;
        #rewrite ^/pinnect/([^.]+)$                                      /pinnect/index.php/$1 last;
        rewrite ^/pinnect/(.*)                                      /pinnect/index.php/$1 last;

        return 200;    
}
```

[Read more…](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#return)

As we are here, you should replace `last` by `break` since you have your instructions in a `location` block.

Also, you might prefer using `?` instead of `(.*)` to drop the original arguments.

[Read more…](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)